# How to write a Java class that is converted to JSON by Log4j2 JSONLayout automatically?

Tags: arrays, log4j2

Log4j2's [JsonLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) converts the LogEvent content to JSON like this:

Java:

```java
  logger.info("This is an info message");
```

Output:

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1598613343782,
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.example.Test",
  "message" : "This is an info message",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "contextMap" : { },
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

But when an object(bean) is passed to `Logger`, it spits the message as string.

Let's say my bean is something like this:

```java
public class MyLogBean {
    private String message;
    private String userId;
    private String ip;
    public MyLogBean(String message, String userId, String ip) {
        this.message = message;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.ip = ip;
    }
    public MyLogBean() {}
    public String getMessage() {return message;}
    public void setMessage(String message) {this.message = message;}
    public String getUserId() {return userId;}
    public void setUserId(String userId) {this.userId = userId;}
    public String getIp() {return ip;}
    public void setIp(String ip) {this.ip = ip;}
}
```

Then if try to write MyLogBean with something like this:
Java:

```java
    logger.info(new MyLogBean("UserLogged","john.appleseed@example.com","192.168.1.56"));
```

Output:

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1598613343782,
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.example.Test",
  "message" : "com.example.MyLogBean@328cf0e1",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "contextMap" : { },
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

It prints `"com.example.MyLogBean@328cf0e1"` as message.

How to make it write the message in JSON like this:

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1598613343782,
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.example.Test",
  "message" : {
      "message":"UserLogged",
      "userId":"john.appleseed@example.com",
      "ip":"192.168.1.56"      
  },
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "contextMap" : { },
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

I need `MyLogBean`class to be converted to JSON automatically by JsonLayout. Unfortunately by default, JsonLayout uses `toString` method and put all object content as string.

I've tried to convert it to JSON by implementing `MyLogBean` class with Log4J [Message](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html) interface but it still uses a string method(`getFormattedMessage`). Even if I use a string to JSON converter, the message again become a string the output become something like this:

```
{
  "message" : "{\"message\":\"UserLogin\",\"userId\":\"john\",\"ip\":\"10.2.3.4\"}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE***: *With the 2.14.0 release of Log4J2, LogstashLayout is now integrated into Log4J2 itself as JsonTemplateLayout.*

It turns out [LogstashLayout](https://github.com/vy/log4j2-logstash-layout) is the custom layout that does the trick.

1. Write `"message": "${json:message:json}"` in `LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json` file.
2. Java object must implement the `MultiformatMessage` and return the JSON string in `getFromattedMessage` method.
3. `getMessageFormats()` method also must return `JSON`.

Comment: FYI - LogstashLayout has moved into Log4j and will be included in the 2.14.0 release as JsonTemplateLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says you should do:

```
<JsonLayout objectMessageAsJsonObject="true"/>
```

If you require the userId and ip on all log events you could add them to the ThreadContextMap. Then they would automatically appear in the contextMap section and you could simply log your message.

Another option option would be to include a toString() method in MyLogBean() that returns the relevant fields as a JSON string.

If you cannot modify the bean class you could create your own IntrospectingMessage that accepts the bean as a parameter and returns a JSON string of all the attributes when getFormattedMessage is called.

Comment: Already used `objectMessageAsJsonObject` but it needs my object to be type of `Map` and unfortunately using `contextMap` for this is not appropriate.

Comment: Updated the answer with a few more suggestions. FYI - Log4j 2.14.0 will include a new JsonTemplateLayout that will provide more flexibility.

Comment: I'm waiting 2.14.0 for this: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/335#issuecomment-683172100